# Does requesting location permission via WebView (Android and iOS) grants permission on native app?

Tags: android, ios, webview, android-webview, wkwebview

Explaining in more words: I need to request location permission via WebView, in both Android and iOS, and then use that permission to get user's actual position, not in the WebView, but now in the native app, whenever necessary.
Is this possible?

Comment: On iOS you need the native app code to request location permission in order for the native app code to get location.  The web view would then need to ask independently if it needed location.

Comment: @Paulw11, but can I ask for location in WebView without asking it on native code?

Comment: If you ask in the web view then JavaScript in that web view can get location. Native code cannot. Further, web view location permissions are not permanent. The user will be asked each time the web view wants to use their location (the user has an option of ticking a box so that their answer is remembered for one day)